# Spock - How to work with repeated interactions

Tags: unit-testing, spock, powermock, powermockito

For few test cases I'm trying to follow a DRY principle, where only the interactions are different with same test case conditions. I'm not able to find a way to implement multiple methods in the `interaction { }` block.

As mentioned in http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/interaction_based_testing.html#_explicit_interaction_blocks, I'm using `interaction { }` in the `then:` block like below:

**Java Code:**

```java
// legacy code (still running on EJB 1.0 framework, and no dependency injection involved)
// can't alter java code base

public voidGetData() {
  DataService ds = new DataService();
  ds = ds.findByOffset(5);
  Long len = ds.getOffset() // happy path scenario; missing a null check
  // other code
}

// other varieties of same code:
public voidGetData2() {
  ItemEJB tmpItem = new ItemEJB();
  ItemEJB item = tmpItem.findByOffset(5);
  if(null != item) {
    Long len = item.getOffset();
    // other code
  }
}

public voidGetData3() {
  ItemEJB item = new ItemEJB().findByOffset(5);
  if(null != item) {
    Long len = item.getOffset();
    // other code
  }
}
```

**Spock Test:**

```
def "test scene1"() {
  given: "a task"
  // other code ommitted
  DataService mockObj = Mock(DataService)

  when: "take action"
  // code omitted

  then: "action response"
  interaction {
    verifyNoDataScenario()    // How to add verifyErrorScenario() interaction to the list?
  }
}

private verifyDataScenario() {
  1 * mockObj.findByOffset(5) >> mockObj // the findByOffset() returns an object, so mapped to same mock instance
  1 * mockObj.getOffset() >> 200
}

private verifyErrorScenario() {
  1 * mockObj.findByOffset(5) >> null // the findByOffset() returns null
  0 * mockObj.getOffset() >> 200  // this won't be executed, and should ie expected to throw NPE
}
```

The `interaction` closure doesn't accept more than one method call. I'm not sure if it's design limitation. I believe more can be done in the closure than just mentioning the method name. I also tried interpolating the mockObj as a variable and use data pipe / data table, but since it's referring the same mock instance, it's not working. I'll post that as a separate question.

I ended up repeating the test case twice just to invoke different interaction methods. Down the line I see more scenarios, and wanted to avoid copy & paste approach. Appreciate any pointers to achieve this.

**Update:**

- Modified shared java code as the earlier DataService name was confusing.
- As there's no DI involved, and I didn't find a way to mock method variables, so I mock them using PowerMockito, e.g. `PowerMockito.whenNew(DataService.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockObj)`

Comment: Hello. You asked a question, I answered it. You didn't provide the MCVE I asked for after your follow-up question. I would appreciate you to accept + upvote my answer because it answers your initial question in quite a lot of detail.

Answer (score 2):

Your application code looks very strange. Is the programming style in your legacy application really that bad? First a `DataService` object is created with a no-arguments constructor, just to be overwritten in the next step by calling a method on that instance which again returns a `DataService` object. What kind of programmer creates code like that? Or did you just make up some pseudo code which does not have much in common with your real application? Please explain.

As for your test code, it also does not make sense because you instantiate `DataService mockObj` as a local variable in your feature method (test method), which means that in your helper method `mockObj` cannot be accessed. So either you need to pass the object as a parameter to the helper methods or you need to make it a field in your test class.

Last, but not least, your local mock object is never injected into the class under test because, as I said in the first paragraph, the `DataService` object in `getData()` is also a local variable. Unless your application code is compeletely fake, there is no way to inject the mock because `getData()` does not have any method parameter and the `DataService` object is not a field which could be set via setter method or constructor. Thus, you can create as many mocks as you want, the application will never have any knowledge of them. So your stubbing `findByOffset(long offset)` (why don't you show the code of that method?) has no effect whatsoever.

Bottom line: Please provide an example reflecting the structure of your real code, both application and test code. The snippets you provide do not make any sense, unfortunately. I am trying to help, but like this I cannot.

---

**Update:**

In my comments I mentioned refactoring your legacy code for testability by adding a constructor, setter method or an overloaded `getData` method with an additional parameter. Here is an example of what I mean:

**Dummy helper class:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q58470315;

public class DataService {
  private long offset;

  public DataService(long offset) {
    this.offset = offset;
  }

  public DataService() {}

  public DataService findByOffset(long offset) {
    return new DataService(offset);
  }

  public long getOffset() {
    return offset;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "DataService{" +
      "offset=" + offset +
      '}';
  }
}
```

**Subject under test:**

Let me add a private `DataService` member with a setter in order to make the object injectable. I am also adding a check if the `ds` member has been injected or not. If not, the code will behave like before in production and create a new object by itself.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q58470315;

public class ToBeTestedWithInteractions {
  private DataService ds;

  public void setDataService(DataService ds) {
    this.ds = ds;
  }

  // legacy code; can't alter
  public void getData() {
    if (ds == null)
      ds = new DataService();
    ds = ds.findByOffset(5);
    Long len = ds.getOffset();
  }
}
```

**Spock test:**

Now let us test both the normal and the error scenario. Actually I think you should break it down into two smaller feature methods, but as you seem to wish to test everything (IMO too much) in one method, you can also do that via two distinct pairs of `when-then` blocks. You do not need to explicitly declare any interaction blocks in order to do so.

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q58470315

import spock.lang.Specification

class RepeatedInteractionsTest extends Specification {
  def "test scene1"() {
    given: "subject under test with injected mock"
    ToBeTestedWithInteractions subjectUnderTest = new ToBeTestedWithInteractions()
    DataService dataService = Mock()
    subjectUnderTest.dataService = dataService

    when: "getting data"
    subjectUnderTest.getData()

    then: "no error, normal return values"
    noExceptionThrown()
    1 * dataService.findByOffset(5) >> dataService
    1 * dataService.getOffset() >> 200

    when: "getting data"
    subjectUnderTest.getData()

    then: "NPE, only first method called"
    thrown NullPointerException
    1 * dataService.findByOffset(5) >> null
    0 * dataService.getOffset()
  }
}
```

Please also note that testing for exceptions thrown or not thrown adds value to the test, the interaction testing just checks internal legacy code behaviour, which has little to no value.

Comment: I admire your reply, but I afraid the java code is from current live environment. It's because of old enterprise frameworks in use, and we're still in the world of EJB 1.0, and no DI yet. Can you believe that? I updated with another java snippet for easy interpretation. If the java code is confusing, you may ignore it, and please feel free to cite simple example. The primary focus is how to execute multiple spock interactions for same given:, when:, then: block instead of duplicating same for different set of interactions.

Comment: DI does not mean a DI framework like Spring or Guice. It could just mean an additional constructor, setter or method parameter with the corresponding argument you want to inject. As for your test code, I have no idea why you think you need an `interaction {}` block there. It is completely unnecessary and might not even do what you think it does. Concerning mocking local variables (similar to global mocks for Groovy code in Spock), there is no other way than using an additional framework like PowerMock, as you already noticed.

Comment: One more copmment about "cannot change legacy code". Of course you can! Just make minimal changes in order to make it mock-testable without using frameworks like PowerMock. Refactoring for testability without changing any other behaviour is a good thing to do. Don't say "cannot" if in reality you mean "choose not to" or "boss won't let me". It is funny that someone expects you to write tests involving legacy code, but won't let you refactor that legacy code for testability in the first place.

Comment: I don't even understand why you are testing interactions (number of method calls) at all here. The test would be tightly coupled to the internal implementation of your legacy class. You better test its behaviour, i.e. that it does the right thing when injecting a normal mock and throws an exception when injecting the error mock.

Comment: Please note: I added an example of what I mean by refactoring for testability to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @kriegaex, Really appreciate your example and emphasis towards behavioral testing.

Comment: I couldn't reply earlier and it fell off my radar a bit. I got one question though. I've lot many steps in the mock verifications, and that's why I prefer to pull it out to separate method and I used interaction block to invoke other private methods. So if the same is applied to your example, will it be possible to call multiple methods with only one given block, like given: when: then: (w/ interaction) , or has it to be done using given: when: then: when: then: as you mentioned. Am I confusing you?

Comment: When I meant "cannot change legacy code", it's because the implementation code is owned by different vendor, and automation testing is handled by us. Its corporate communication / business, and not technical issue. It's completely different world. I just gave an example of java code, please don't take it otherwise. The complete focus for this question is only on spock test, that to precisely on the then: block behavior using interaction keyword.

Comment: Sorry for answering late, I was very busy the last few weeks. Actually I cannot answer your follow-up questions without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I tried to help you based on your pseudo code, but then you said the real situation is different. So either you illustrate your problem with the MCVE or we are done here. I like to help, really. But if you still cannot accept my answer as it is, I have nothing else to say with the amount of information you provide.